# check url variable is valid in php

Tags: php, url

hi I have a site where the links menu is read from a database and created in the format of index.php?page=mypage

how can I check that "mypage" is a page that exists in the database, so that users can't just add anything into the url?

thanks xx

Comment: Database? What database? If the data is read from the database, how can it **NOT** be in the database - unless your database is a very long way from being normalized.

Comment: I was concerned about the user putting their own value in the url that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are stored within the database: check the result set of the SQL-Query you´re sending to the database and don´t forget to escape characters to deny possible SQL-injection... ( `mysql_real_escape_string()` )

Answer (score 1):

Use a whitelist approach, something like this:

```
$allowedKeys = array('myPage', 'yourPage', '...Page');

$_GET = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($allowedKeys));
```